# Access to CSS file name in javascript compiled by webpack

Tags: css, webpack

For a WYSIWYG rich text editor I need to provide the URL to a CSS file which I want to compile with Webpack. The javascript is of course also compiled with Webpack. How can I have access to or how do I know about the path/names of the compiled CSS files?